# CSS3 Animation - Change image on 'underside' of an animated element

Tags: css, css-animations

I am using CSS3 animation to have a door element open on hover. If you take a look at the url below: http://www.superfreebingo.com/advent-lp/

When you hover over a box the css animation will begin showing you content beneath.

I would like to modify the 'underside' of the door that opens, you will notice at the moment you just see the front image in reverse..

Will it be a case of timing another animation on the background image itself to coincide with the point the door 'flips' over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you are looking for is `backface-visibilty`. Set that to the `.box img`.

Now add an element **below** that image, here I just added a `pseudo-element`, positioned it absolute with `z-index: -1;`.

You could also just set a `div` or `image` as a child of `.box`, works just as well.

```css
/* CSS needed for your affect */

.box img {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.box::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #FF0;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* Rest of the markup */

article {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
  margin: .5em;
  perspective: 850px;
}
article:hover .box {
  transition: .5s ease-in;
  transform: rotateY(-97deg);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  perspective-origin: 0;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  transition: all .3s;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 850px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.box, .present {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.box img, .present img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.present {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), inset 0 0 30px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
.present a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="box">
     <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wheDD.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="present">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXU8x.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
</article>
```